# How can I determine which memory region of jvm an object is located in?

Tags: java, jvm

I know that jvm determines whether an object is to be reclaimed by reachability analysis, and different memory regions have different gc algorithms, but does the object itself store some information indicating the memory region to which it belongs, whether it is new or old.Or there may be other information that indicates.Or maybe the question is not important at all?

jvm determines which region of the object exists, perhaps by the gc age in the object header.i'm not sure

Comment: If you could find this out, what would you do with the information?

Comment: The memory address of an object will tell the garbage collector(s) what region the object is in.  But you (the programmer) don't need to know that.

Comment: If you have a can of beans, do the beans contain information regarding which can they are in?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.